# Making image move across screen in python

Tags: python, graphics

Most of the posts about this involve pygame which I don't know if I am using or not. 
We have a `graphic.py` file we can use, and we were supposed to make shapes that resemble a sail boat (still working on that) and make that boat move across the screen.

So, after I make such a shape, my plan was to set the position to the left of the screen and then write a for loop which would increase the position in the X axis as it went through.

About this line, does the increment matter?

```
for i in range(-(what x is at start),(where I want x to end),1):
```

and about this one, how do I get the X value of image position and change that I know it is not `image.x` ?

```
image.x=i #
```

So I would assign image to the shape? Is this possible? or do I need to make a function that creates the image?

Comment: This is very hard to answer without seeing the documentation or source code for graphic.py.

Comment: `image.x = i` is setting the `x` direction position of the image to `i`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is there something at the top of the code that says

```
import pygame
```

if so you are using pygame.

Also if you could show us the actual source code then it will be much easier for us to answer your question.